# How to highlight first negative number inn Table in Tableau?

Tags: highlight, tableau-desktop

Table contains date and ice-cream sales. Based on Ice cream field highlight the 1st negative number.

I am creating a calculation field using the Index function.
Indexing func:
IF SUM([Sales]) < 0 THEN INDEX()
END

And I am comparing it with the actual index function [![enter image description here][1]][1]below.

Index() = Indexing func
I dragged this comparison calc field to color, whenever it matches it should highlight the 1st negative number.

But it is highlighting all the negative numbers in the field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d6uD.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're only checking whether a value is negative, but you're saying you want to check whether that value is negative and it's the first negative value, so your calculation should really be SUM([Sales]) < 0 AND LOOKUP(SUM([Sales]),-1) > 0. I'm not sure why you're using two indexes, you could just colour where the calculation above wasn't NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that works when you are **not** using Date as dimension on your view. Otherwise, you can definitely use table calcs - which work but are a bit trickier.

Create a calculated field that holds the Date if it meet
s your selection criteria (negative sales in this case) and will be null otherwise. Call the field something like **Date_With_Negative_Sales**

```
if [Sales] < 0 then [Date] end
```

Then you can use **Date_With_Negative_Sales** on the view as a measure, with either MIN() or MAX() to show the first date or last date with negative sales.